# C# fast eventHandler calling

Tags: c#, event-handling, locking

I'm doing a simple 2D railway  simulator and I'm stuck on building a straight rail.
I have a map made of small PictureBoxes(control) used as blocks for building. I want to achieve: I click on a block and move mouse e.g. left and right, and my rails whould appear and dissapear just as I move from and back to my startingPoint block.

I have achieved it with this code:

```
        public static void HandleMouseEnterWhileBuilding(Block sender) //only while building straights
        {
            if (sender.x - startingPoint.x >= sender.y - startingPoint.y && currentRotation == "horizontal") //then keep it horizontal
            {               
                    for (int i = 0; i < currentlyPrebuilt.Count; i++)
                    {
                        currentlyPrebuilt[i].Image = null;
                    }
                    currentlyPrebuilt.Clear();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= sender.x - startingPoint.x; i++) //prefills all wanted blocks with rails
                    {
                        currentlyPrebuilt.Add(MainForm.map[startingPoint.x + i, startingPoint.y]);
                        MainForm.map[startingPoint.x + i, startingPoint.y].ImageLocation = @"Images\horizontalRail.png";
                    }                    
            }
        }
```

It's just a branch for building rails to the right of the startingPoint and **it works only when I move my mouse really slow**. If I move mouse to the right fast, it builds all the wanted blocks of rails, but when I move it left back to the starting point, it 'forgets' to remove some, or sometimes all the rails, which is wierd, cause in the code, every image from `currentlyPrebuilt` List<> gets deleted before it is cleared and it seems like clear operation overtakes it and some rails never get deleted, cause they are no longer in the List.

So can it happen, that when there's a new event, the execution of the previous handler skips?

My assumption was that there are so many eventhandler calls, that they starts new threads which work on same structure, but i got informed that UI calls don't start new threads.

When I remove the line `currentlyPrebuilt.Clear();`, it works pretty fine although it lefts some blocks anyway, but on several more mouseEnters(my event) it eventually removes everything the user wants. However, it feels just bad to fill that List with pointers infinitely.

Comment: For your information, events originating from the UI are all processed on a single thread (valid for WinForms, WPF, and many other UI Frameworks). This makes locking unnecessary as they won't be executed in parallel anyway.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll edit the question.

Comment: what do you mean with "small pictureboxes"?

Comment: many e.g. 20x20 px Pictureboxes creating a 2D map of blocks.

Comment: The picturebox control or something you've created yourself?

Comment: Yes, the control, just edited

Comment: It's not meant for that kind of usage. It will go faster if you draw the images by yourself. Look at the `Graphics` object.